# Where does the code pertaing to fastboot mode reside?

Tags: internal-storage, rom-flashing, fastboot, rom, bootloader

Is it in the primary-bootloader (on the mb), or the secondary-bootloader(on the emmc)?

My motive behid the question is to understand what other codes are executed before system can get into fastboot mode

(Recently, I've been tinkering with a lot of different android devices and have tried to read up whatever comes up upon web-searches regarding "fastboot", "bootloaders", "primary bootloader", "secondary bootloaders". But this is one question I can't find any definitive answer about.)

Comment: Any details needed?

Comment: I will be blunt. It sits on its own partition, and can only really be touched by special programs. Download partitions viewer, it may show you what you need.

Comment: My motive behid the question was to understand what other codes are executed before system can get into fastboot mode.

Comment: fair enough, though no idea how to answer your q.

Comment: You can try asking in the aosp email thread.

Comment: @Fabio Do you mean to suggest mailing to AOSP or ask on their forums?

Comment: AOSP forums, or even better now that I remember there's a lot of developers with deep knowledge of android internals on http://forum.xda-developers.com/. I don't know much about those details but it's possible that you need to narrow down the question/answer to a specific phone model/android version.

Comment: Thanks for the link; it just didn't occur to me i could ask it there?

Comment: Look, what I found: " fastboot mode can start on your device even before Android loads (and can even run when Android isn't installed at all), fastboot mode is useful for updating the firmware quickly, without having to use a recovery mode. In fact, it's frequently the preferred way to initially install the recovery image on many devices. "https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_fastboot_intro

Answer (score 0):

Fastboot mode is in the bootloader and usually resides in a /dev/block, none of this is open sourced.