# where is the binary for fastboot mode located and How can I get a copy of it?

Tags: rom-flashing, internal-storage, fastboot, rom

## Edit

Thanks to everyone in the commen section, `lk.img` seems to be what I was looking for and it is indeed right, because it has strings for varies commands like

```
oem p2u
oem reboot-recovery
oem off-mode-charge
```

the `lk.img` for my phone can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r2wgh7GLZJUE1NN7LWCmpmXoKOcbqRFv/view?usp=sharing)

The only thing left is to `reverse engineer` it but most programs I use cannot figure out what file type it is

### Motive

I am trying to find the binary for [fastboot mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastboot)
in my phone
So that I can understand what my phone 's vendor `fastboot` does when I send
a command using ***fastboot protocol***

### what Have I Tried

#### 1

I read fastboot's source code [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/core/fastboot/)

in the [Android.bp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/core/fastboot/Android.bp)

```
cc_binary {
    name: "fastbootd",
    defaults: ["fastboot_defaults"],

    recovery: true,

    product_variables: {
        debuggable: {
            cppflags: ["-DFB_ENABLE_FETCH"],
        },
    },

    srcs: [
        "device/commands.cpp",
        "device/fastboot_device.cpp",
        "device/flashing.cpp",
        "device/main.cpp",
        "device/usb.cpp",
        "device/usb_client.cpp",
        "device/tcp_client.cpp",
        "device/utility.cpp",
        "device/variables.cpp",
        "socket.cpp",
    ],
```

it seems that the fastboot's program on the android phone will be compiled with name `fastbootd`,

So I tried finding it by downloading my phone's official firmware and locating it using linux's `find` but it doesn't seem to reside in the firmware

#### 2

I have read [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/152720/where-does-the-code-pertaing-to-fastboot-mode-reside)

But it didn't tell in more detail on how to get
a copy of the binary and doesn't seem to have satisfactory answer

### Phone details

Not sure if it matters because I think all android's `fastboot` binary should be in the same location

```
Model Number : vivo1819
vivo ROM : Funtouch OS 10.5
Android version : 11
Hardware Version No. : MP_0.1
Software Version : PD1831F_EX_A_8.1.48
```

#### Firmware Download

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13coKM6yMS39MVRauyyZ7FO3B_twlTB1a/view?usp=sharing

### Question

So how can I get my phone's `fastboot` so that I can get a copy and learn more about it via `reverse engineering`

Comment: fastboot is not a binary that is executed, instead it is more something like a mini-OS itself.

Comment: Get a dump of partition named `aboot` or `abl` or something similar. The same can be extracted from firmware zip.

Comment: git://codeaurora.org/kernel/lk.git

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-discover-hidden-fastboot-commands

Comment: @alecxs how can I do it if I don't have root  and only having the firmware?

I have tried finding it in my firmwares, when I mounted `system.img` but 
`/dev/` is empty

Comment: @IrfanLatif can you explain to me how to get the dump of partition named `aboot`?
the firmwares I got contains mostly of `img` files. I have tried to mount several of the `img` files like `vendor.img` and `system.img` but still cannot find it either

Comment: @alecxs alright thanks, in my case I have `lk.img` in the firmware,
and when I looked at the strings it does seems to be the `fastboot` .

how can I mount `lk.img` because unlike other images inside the firmware
its filetype is unknown when I use `file` command on linux

I cannot use `simg2img` command on it to mount it

Comment: http://www.lieberbiber.de/2015/07/05/mediatek-details-little-kernel

Comment: @RikuPotato bootloaders are binaries - usually closed-source and signed with OEM's private key in case of Android - not filesystems. You cannot *"mount"* the file, though it's named `.img`. You need to reverse-engineer it. But better have a look at LK source code first. It's open-source. But it won't have OEM-specific changes.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks for the tips, I will be updating my progress soon

Comment: if you want to become reverse engineer, learn reverse engineering. this is a skill, not a software. tools like ghidra or ida can help decompiling assembly to C code, but cannot reveal source code (besides this is off-topic here, we have sister site for [reverseengineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10701) questions)

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!